# How to get <w:p> elements that are not having ancestor of <v:group>using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                       xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<w:body>
<w:p> <!-- Assume Current Node -->
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:r>
     <w:t>Sample data</w:t>
  </w:r>

  <w:r>
    <w:pict>
       <v:group>
         <v:shape>
            <v:textbox>
              <w:txbxContent>
                 <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Sample data1</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                  </w:p>
              </w:txbxContent>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:shape>
         <v:shape>
            <v:textbox>
              <w:txbxContent>
                 <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Sample data2</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                  </w:p>
              </w:txbxContent>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:shape>
       </v:group>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

My required XML transformation result should look like this :

```
<Document>
   <paragraph>sample data</paragraph>
   <group>
        <paragraph>sample data1</paragraph>
        <paragraph>sample data1</paragraph>
    </group>
</Document>
```

My current XSLT snippet is

```
<Document>
<xsl:template match="//w:body/w:p">
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::w:p//v:group">

              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::w:p[not(ancestor::v:group)]">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="self::w:p"><!--this template take care about getting data inside w:p-->
              </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              <group>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p"> <!--this template take care about getting data inside w:p-->
                </xsl:apply-templates>
             </group>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</Document>
```

But it produced output like this :

```
<Document>
 <paragraph>sample data</paragraph>
 <paragraph>sample data1</paragraph>
 <paragraph>sample data2</paragraph>
 <group>
   <paragraph>sample data1</paragraph>
   <paragraph>sample data2</paragraph>
 </group>
</Document>
```

How can I achieve the correct result that I mentioned above?

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't clear at all. Please, edit and specify clearly what nodes you want to be processed.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev :Just Assume first <w:p> is currentnode.So, in my for loop i get next <w:p>... so i want to process from second <w:p>...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:My For each loop first time taking the following-sibling of first <w:p>.So, in this case,for each loop take the second <w:p> to further process.because, it is a immediate following-sibling of the first <w:p>.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:Please See now my updated xslt snippt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//w:body/w:p/w:r">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="v:group">
    <group>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="..//w:t" />    
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:t">
    <paragraph>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </paragraph>
</xsl:template>
```

it gives:

```
<Document>
  <paragraph>Sample data</paragraph>
  <group>
    <paragraph>Sample data1</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Sample data2</paragraph>
  </group>
</Document>
```

**Update**: added new template `<xsl:template match="//w:body/w:p/w:r">` to be independent from top level *paragraph* and *group* element order

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.But i want to use for each loop to get that.Because,it is not complete xslt file.It is a snippt.Please try to get it using foreach loop.and also see my updated xslt code snippt for your clear reference...

Comment: @Saravanan: in XSLT, it is not common to use `xsl:for-each` (unless when dealing with non-nodes, like strings or integers), because requirements like yours are very hard to express that way. Instead, you should use a template-based approach like Vitaliy showed here. That way, all the nesting, recursion etc is done by the processor and you can have a clean and simple structure in your XSLT which is easy to maintain.